# Emacs: How to generate etags for coffeescript?

Tags: emacs, coffeescript, etag, emacs24

I just found the [coffeetags](https://github.com/lukaszkorecki/coffeetags) tool and can confirm that it works with vim.

Is there something similar for Emacs? Has anyone managed to get etags working for Emacs with coffeescript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried [following recipe](https://gist.github.com/wereHamster/1299204)? But you may need to use [exuberant ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/), not default etags...

Answer (score 6):

This it what I've done (thanks to Alex Ott for the link):

1. Install Exuberant ctags via Emacs package manager
2. Install ctags
3. Create a `.ctags` file in your project root directory ([here](https://gist.github.com/rosenfeld/2405554) is the link to the original Gist):

   ```
   --langdef=CoffeeScript
   --langmap=CoffeeScript:.coffee
   --regex-CoffeeScript=/(^|=[ \t])*class ([A-Za-z.]+)( extends [A-Za-z.]+)?$/\2/c,class/
   --regex-CoffeeScript=/^[ \t]*@?([A-Za-z.]+):.*[-=]>.*$/\1/f,function/
   --regex-CoffeeScript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z.]+)[ \t]+=.*[-=]>.*$/\1/f,function/
   --regex-CoffeeScript=/^[ \t]*([A-Za-z.]+)[ \t]+=[^->\n]*$/\1/v,variable/
   ```
4. Generate the TAGS file: `ctags -e -R source_folder`

Comment: ctags does not have the `-e` option on my vm. Try `etas -R source_folder` in case you don't either.

Comment: Aren't [these definitions](https://gist.github.com/bjornharrtell/2901844) better? And by the way, why do you not quote them? The way they're given, they won't work in any shell that I know.